# How can I update a CSV stored on AWS S3 with a Python script?

Tags: python, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a CSV which is stored in an AWS S3 bucket and is used to store information which gets loaded into a HTML document via some jQuery.

I also have a Python script which is currently sat on my local machine ready to be used. This Python script scrapes another website and saves the information to the CSV file which I then upload to my AWS S3 bucket.

I am trying to figure out a way that I can have the Python script run nightly and overwrite the CSV stored in the S3 bucket. I cannot seem to find a similar solution to my problem online and am vastly out of my depth when it comes to AWS.

Does anyone have any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Why was this flagged within 5 seconds for being too broad? I have quite clearly outlined the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheapest way: Modify your Python script to work as an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function, then schedule it to run nightly.

Easiest way: Spin up an [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance, copy the script to the instance, and schedule it to run nightly via [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: I managed to get it setup on an AWS Lambda function using boto3, worked like a dream